# Répétition du sujet sous forme de pronom dans les questions

Tags: usage, questions, pronoms-interrogatifs

Des phrases interrogatives telles que « Comment le prisonnier a-t-il pu s'évader? » sont assez courantes et il semble parfois que l'on ne puisse pas exprimer leur contenu autrement; par exemple « Comment le prisonnier a pu s'évader? » se dit aussi mais laisse dans l'esprit l'impression de ne pas dire tout à fait la même chose. Dans certain cas, par exemple avec des modifications apportées à la phrase une sorte de légitimité semble être restituée à l'énoncé dans sa forme sans répétition en tant que moyen d'exprimer pleinement  ce que la forme avec répétition communique; le malaise apparent dans la compréhension semble avoir disparu; voici un exemple;

> Comment le prisonnier aurait pu s'évader puisqu'il y avait en permanence un garde à sa porte?

On peut néanmoins utiliser dans cette dernière la répétition du sujet sans l'alourdir ou en changer le sens.

- Est-ce que l'on peut écarter l'idée suivante que dans le cas avec répétition on insisterais sur le caractère inimaginable de la situation alors que dans le cas sans répétition la question se trouverais à un niveau plus pragmatique en cela qu'elle porterait l'attention sur la question du moyen utilisé? (Cette possibilité semble assez improbable et de toute façon au plus une particularité à caractère local puisque il n'est pas question uniquement de l'exemple choisi mais de toutes les questions sur le modèle qu'il incarne, cependant penser tant soi peu à la différence entre ces énoncés insinue dans mon esprit cet état de chose comme une explication plausible.)
- S'il n'y a aucune différence de sens, cette différence dans l'effet ressenti pourrait-elle n'être que subjective?
- Si elle est objective l'utilisation ou la non utilisation de la répétition est-elle expliquée en relation à ce phénomène?
- Autrement, indépendamment de toute explication sur le plan du rôle de renforcement qui pourrait être joué par la répétition, y a-t-il un principe qui dicterait l'usage de la répétition ou bien ne serait-il question que de registre de langue?

Comment: Houla! C'est très intéressant mais très complexe car il faut remonter à une très vieille grammaire pour comprendre le coup de l'inversion verbe-sujet. J'essayerai une réponse ce W.E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui! C'est marrant ces phrases à, on pourrait presque dire, deux sujets.

D'autant plus marrant qu'en ancien français, comme en latin... de sujet, on n'en mettait souvent... pas du tout, la désinence du verbe suffisant à préciser la personne.

Et encore plus marrant que sa répétition semble parfois si inutile étant donnée la proximité du référent qu'on cherche parfois à l'en éloigner en intercalant une virgule et l'interrogatif, donnant ainsi une troisième possibilité de formuler ta question : *Et le prisonnier **, comment** a-t-il pu s'évader ?*

Mais comme nous allons le voir... tout ceci n'est que... de bonne et simple logique!

L'inversion verbe-sujet dont témoigne ce *a-t-il* n'a strictement rien à voir avec l'inversion traditionnelle rencontrée dans les phrases interrogatives.

L'inversion verbe-sujet dans une phrase interrogative simple est commandée par le besoin de la différencier d'une affirmative et par le fait que dans une interrogative simple, l'interrogation porte sur le verbe. => On va le balancer en premier ce qui donnerait fort logiquement pour un Français du XIIe curieux de savoir si vos amis partent : *Partent vos amis ?* (J'ai un peu traduit ;-) )

Quand, comme c'est le cas ici avec *comment*, la question comporte un pronom ou adverbe interrogatif, ce dernier est à l'évidence suffisant pour marquer l'interrogation sans nécessité de maintenir l'inversion verbe-sujet.
Cette inversion-là qui subsiste n'est donc nullement liée au besoin de marquer l'interrogation mais bien plutôt au respect d'une règle très générale en ancien français :

Tout déterminant du verbe (nom, pronom, adjectif, adverbe) placé en tête de phrase entraîne **nécessairement** l'inversion du verbe! Point! Même, et d'abord dans le cas de phrases affirmatives.

Le français moderne conserve d'ailleurs quelques reliques de cette règle d'inversion. Ainsi une phrase affirmative que l'on pourrait très bien formuler ainsi :

***À plus forte raison, aurait-il*** dû s'évader

*Ainsi a-t-il pu s'évader.*

De cette logique grammaticale, on conclura que, dans *Comment le prisonnier a-t-il pu s'évader?*, *Comment* marque l'interrogation et le *a-t-il* est une relique toute faite de l'application d'une règle d'application systématique en AF concernant toute phrase débutant par un déterminant du verbe.

---

S'évade le prisonnier ? Le prisonnier s'évade ?....

On l'a dit, dans une interrogation simple, l'interrogation porte sur le verbe.
Mais il peut arriver que l'on désire faire porter l'interrogation sur le sujet.

On se trouve alors devant un véritable casse-tête. car il faudrait, à la fois placer le sujet avant le verbe pour lui donner plus d'importance ET... le garder après le verbe afin de ne pas transformer l'interrogation en affirmation.

La solution s'impose alors logiquement... on mettra le sujet avant ET après :

*Le prisonnier s'évade le prisonnier ?* => le pronom pour éviter la répétition : => *Le prisonnier s'évade-t-il ?*

Génial non ?

Par souci de simplicité, La tournure contaminera alors les interrogatives avec mot interrogatif.
Mais, historiquement d'abord sous la forme soulignée en début de réponse en maximisant l'éloignement : *Et le prisonnier, comment a-t-il pu s'évader ?*

Bon... je suis passé rapidement de l'AF au moderne... il aura néanmoins fallu du temps pour en arriver là, d'autres solutions (très logiques elles aussi) avaient entre temps émergé comme par exemple mettre le verbe à l'infinitif. Pas con ça l'infinitif! Ça dispense du sujet.

Ainsi Froissart dans ses *Chroniques* aurait sans aucun doute préféré écrire :

*Comment le prisonnier s'être évadé* (J'ai évidemment adapté un *Cuident cil François avoir reconquis...*) qui aurait tout aussi bien pu logiquement l'emporter si... l'usage ne l'avait pas... ignoré.

Que de la logique donc que du très objectif dans tout cela.... *Toi ne pas trouver ?* ;-) (J'aime bien Froissart)

Comment: Tous les intéressé dans ce sujet devront vous remercier pour l'effort d'explication que vous mettez en œuvre et les compléments non négligeables que vous fournissez dans un but de mieux  le situer.  La question est essentiellement résolue; je ne suis cependant pas d'accord sur certains points dont je ne résumerai la problématique que d'un seul; «Et le prisonnier, …»; il ne s'agit pas d'une autre formulation de la question mais de sa formulation combinée avec une autre idée, l'idée de la transition dans le discours d'une chose donnée vers la situation du prisonnier.

Comment: @user168676 : Oui +1 pour l'objection. Mais je crois que l'idée de transition, de combinaison avec une autre idée est forcée par le seul *Et* initial usuellement pris en tant que conjonction de coordination. Mais il n'a pas toujours cette fonction. Il m'arrive, lorsque je veux renforcer un terme de l'utiliser sans fonction de coordination : *Ta question était **et** pertinente et légitime*. Le problème est ici dans le cadre du renforcement du sujet. Ce  *Et* initial n'a, à mon opinion, que cette fonction de renforcement. On aurait d'ailleurs aussi bien pu s'en dispenser... (cf suite)

Comment: @user168676 : (...suite) en donnant le départ sous forme exclamative : *Ce prisonnier! Comment a-t-il pu s'évader.*

Comment: J'identifie maintenant le tour particulier qui est donné à ce « et »; merci de cette précision importante.